# Papers which show that a composite fermion VEV is nonzero?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, fermions

I'm trying to find examples for which a theory is shown to have a nonzero composite fermion VEV of the form

$$\langle\overline{\psi}M\psi\rangle\neq 0$$

Where $M$ is some matrix. Are you aware of any papers which work this type of problem out? I am interested specifically in papers which tackle this problem in the continuum, but a lattice paper would be of good use as well.

Comment: You got [Scherer 2002](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0210398) under your belt already?

Comment: Famously, $\mathcal N=1$ Yang-Mills has a gluino condensate due to monopole condensation (cf. Seiberg-Witten).